# How can I get list of url visited for all browser in android device?

Tags: android, cursor, browser

I know following code works but it only for default browser.

I want for all browser installed in device.

```
Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                            Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);


                    mCur.moveToFirst();
                    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                            Log.v("titleIdx",
                                    mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                            Log.v("urlIdx",
                                    mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                            long dateTime = Long.parseLong(mCur
                                    .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX));
                            cal.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);
                            Log.i("Date", cal.getTime().toString());
                            mCur.moveToNext();


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the browser (Chrome, etc.) exposes an explicit interface for this, you can't. And that is a good thing too. I don't want random apps checking what I have visited on my device. What are you trying to build? I sincerely hope it is not spyware...